# separately publish maven attachments

Tags: maven, maven-nar-plugin

I'm building NARs on multiple platforms (Mac and Windows).  The build is complicated and can't be done via the Maven NAR plugin as such, but I'm building the nar files myself and using the `mvn` command-line tool for deployment.

The typical way to do deployment is in one shot, e.g.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
    -Dfile=foobar.jar \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -Dfiles=foobar-x86_64-MacOSX-gcc-shared.nar,foobar-x86_64-Windows-MSVC-shared.nar \
    -Dclassifiers=x86_64-MacOSX-gcc-shared,x86_64-Windows-MSVC-shared \
    -Dtypes=nar,nar \
    -DgroupId=com.example \
    -DartifactId=foobar \
    -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT \
    -Durl=$URL \
    -DrepositoryId=nexus
```

However, because the builds are running on different boxes, the publishing step can't happen in one shot. Ideally, I'd like to be able to "append" the attachments to the primary artifact as the builds finish. ie.,

Run this once:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
    -Dfile=foobar.jar \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -DgroupId=com.example \
    -DartifactId=foobar \
    -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT \
    -Durl=$URL \
    -DrepositoryId=nexus
```

Then on the Mac build slave:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
    -Dfiles=foobar-x86_64-MacOSX-gcc-shared.nar \
    -Dclassifiers=x86_64-MacOSX-gcc-shared \
    -Dtypes=nar \
    -DgroupId=com.example \
    -DartifactId=foobar \
    -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT \
    -Durl=$URL \
    -DrepositoryId=nexus
```

Then on the Windows build slave:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
    -Dfiles=foobar-x86_64-Windows-MSVC-shared.nar \
    -Dclassifiers=x86_64-Windows-MSVC-shared \
    -Dtypes=nar \
    -DgroupId=com.example \
    -DartifactId=foobar \
    -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT \
    -Durl=$URL \
    -DrepositoryId=nexus
```

The first command works fine, of course.  But the two build slave commands fail with

```
The parameters 'file' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file are missing or invalid
```

because it thinks it needs the primary artifact.

How can I specify that I'm *appending* to the publication, not creating an entirely new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because the builds are running on different boxes, the publishing step can't happen in one shot.

If you are using a CI server like Jenkins to perform your builds, you can publish the artifacts from each slave and then access them via a downstream job on the master node.

This is how we solve the issue in the [ImageJ](http://imagej.net/) project: we have [our Jenkins](http://jenkins.imagej.net/) aggregate all the build artifacts, then deploy them all at once. First, the [ImageJ-launcher](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ-launcher/) job—a multi-configuration project—builds the code using the appropriate slaves, archiving the relevant artifacts (which transfers them to the master node's file system). Then the [ImageJ-launcher-deploy](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ-launcher-deploy/) job copies the archived artifacts from each configuration into a single directory for deployment in one shot.

In case it helps, here is the portion of the `ImageJ-launcher-deploy` shell script responsible for copying the NAR artifacts into one place:

```
masterDir=workspace/label/master/target &&
axesDirs=configurations/axis-label/*/builds/$buildNumber/archive/target &&
: copy the nar/**/* files from all axes to master &&
for path in $axesDirs/nar/*/bin/*/*
do
        file=${path#$axesDirs/} &&
        if test -f $masterDir/$file
        then
                # we ignore everything except Linux in the master
                case "$path" in
                */master/*Linux*)
                        ;;
                */master/*)
                        continue
                        ;;
                esac

                cmp $path $masterDir/$file && continue
                printf 'Artifacts disagree:\n%s\n%s\n\n' $path $masterDir/$file
                errors=$(($errors+1))
        else
                target=$masterDir/$file &&
                mkdir -p ${target%/*} &&
                cp $path $target
        fi
done
```

You may not even need to copy the artifacts if `-Dfiles` supports a list of files in different directories—just build up the list of files in the `for` loop, and finish with the `mvn deploy:deploy-file` invocation you gave above.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12825066/1207769) for further details on the ImageJ-launcher Jenkins configuration.

Comment: It's too bad that Maven doesn't allow appending artifacts.  :(  But this approach is the best way given the constraints.  Thanks!